# Unable to integrated react-paypal-button-v2 in react app

Tags: reactjs, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate [react-paypal-button-v2][1] in my react app but after filling the details it is showing `Something went wrong`

```
     <PayPalButton
        amount="0.01"
        onSuccess={(details, data) => {
          console.log(details,"data")
          alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);

          // OPTIONAL: Call your server to save the transaction
          // return fetch("/paypal-transaction-complete", {
          //   method: "post",
          //   body: JSON.stringify({
          //     orderID: data.orderID
          //   })
          // });
        }}
           catchError={(err)=>{
          console.log(err)
            alert(err)

         }
          }
        onError ={(err)=>{
          alert(err)
       console.log(err)

       }
      }
    options={{
          clientId: "xxxxxx"
        }}
      />
```

this is first screen shot once page load
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

this is the second screen shot when I click on mastercard option
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

and this is third screen shot when I click on pay now button  then  its shwo processing but after sometime its show me this page.

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

If click on try again button its redirect to the sandbox and ask for singup

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

I have not integrated any payment getaway in any  app so far, that's why I am not able to figure it out that what might cause of it, why its throwing error.

Please your help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Also, is everything ok with your credit card? Did you test it in production? (it can be specific to the sandbox environment)

Comment: Yes, I tested with production with client id but getting same issue no error showing in console so far.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I am using my debit card but not filling correct address, does address effected it ?

Comment: Hm.. Not that i know of but to remove any doubts just fill it with the correct address and test both in sandbox and production.

Comment: yes, but I don't think address would be effect because  many time we do not fill correct address while paying any other bills or amount.

Comment: In sandbox you're using `clientId: "sb"`?

Comment: you mean here `options={{
          clientId: "ATO9ZZKdCFyEG17kp6w4c8774wn-1NC9W1-mRQ9E0wbKZ1r1- 
          IDCbIkjeFAl4Xz2qchcQgbNW3mVohou"
        }}` ??

Comment: Yes, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2#small_blue_diamond-options-prop-fieldnames-or-parameters

Comment: I have tried with suing `clientId:"sb"` but same issue

Comment: Does it work on localhost ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean to say can we test on localhost ?

Comment: sorry, I can't atm, currently on my phone.

Comment: No, I mean if I test on my localhost so it should work

Comment: Yes, i do my testing locally first

Comment: ok, please get back to me if you done it

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres hi, still not resolved

Comment: Is your goal to implement the PayPal button or to implement using this specific one?

Comment: I suggest you also ask the question [here](https://github.com/Luehang/react-paypal-button-v2/issues) to get a faster answer.