# Unable to make test transaction using react paypal button v2 in react app

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate react papapl button v2 package in my react project but unable to get response. every time getting error with `something went wrong`

I have already posted this question here in [Unable to integrated react-paypal-button-v2 in react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448782/unable-to-integrated-react-paypal-button-v2-in-react-app?noredirect=1#comment103237222_58448782)    but did not got any helpful source.

I am struggling for the last 2 days to resolve it but I could not so far.

Please anyone can guide me or can help me with the issue,

Your assist would be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: What credit card numbers are you using?  The paypal sandbox has special numbers you are supposed to use.

Comment: @SteveK I am using master card

Comment: I looked into it a little more and it looks like it might be a bug but I'm not for sure.  Previously when you clicked on a card there would be a popup now the credit card fields show below the button.  This is a new feature and I am experiencing the same issue that you are.  I opened a support ticket with paypal I urge you to do the same and if you hear back from them let me know.  If I hear back from them I will let you know as well.

Comment: @SteveK sure I trying to reach out paypal support team, if once I got an clue will come back here.